# DbLink result comparison

Tags: postgresql

Hello does anyone know what this piece of code does ?

```
   String innerTarget = dbLink ? MessageFormat.format(INNER_SELECT_TEMPLATE, targetConnect,
    qc.getColumnList(), table, qc.getTableDef()) : MessageFormat.format(INNER_SELECT_TEMPLATE_SCHEMA,
    qc.getColumnList(), targetName, table);
```

Comment: Is there any context?

Comment: That seems to be Java code. I don't see any relation to Postgres or even a DbLink